# POST to Web API action with IEnumerable<Interface> type parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to post to a Web API method from a client, as follows:

```
// Create list of messages that will be sent
IEnumerable<IMessageApiEntity> messages = new List<IMessageApiEntity>();
// Add messages to the list here. 
// They are all different types that implement the IMessageApiEntity interface.

// Create http client
HttpClient client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"])};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

// Post to web api
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Communications/Messages", messages).Result;

// Read results
IEnumerable<ApiResponse<IMessageApiEntity>> results = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ApiResponse<IMessageApiEntity>>>().Result;
```

My Web API controller action looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<IMessageApiEntity> messages)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The problem I am having is that **`messages` is always empty (but not null) when coming into the web API controller action**. I have verified in the debugger that the `messages` object on the client side does have items in it right before being posted.

I suspect it might have something to do with the interface type not being converted to a concrete type when trying to pass the objects, but I don't know how to go about making it work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out how to do it without a custom model binder. Posting the answer in case anyone else has this issue...

Client:

```
// Create list of messages that will be sent
IEnumerable<IMessageApiEntity> messages = new List<IMessageApiEntity>();
// Add messages to the list here. 
// They are all different types that implement the IMessageApiEntity interface.

// Create http client
HttpClient client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"])};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

// Post to web api (this is the part that changed)
JsonMediaTypeFormatter json = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings =
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    }
};
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("Communications/Messages", messages, json).Result;

// Read results
IEnumerable<ApiResponse<IMessageApiEntity>> results = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ApiResponse<IMessageApiEntity>>>().Result;
```

Add to `Register` method in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

The key is to send the type as part of the json and turn on automatic type name handling, so that web API can figure out what type it is.

Comment: Instead of instantiating a new `SerializerSettings` I suggest updating the default (just access it the way you do in your `WebApiConfig.cs`). This way you don't lose other default serializer settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago with .NET Core WebAPI. 
The proposed solution of adding the line below did not work for me:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

I ended up creating a generic object that can carry my IEnumerable, where T is my intended class

```
[Serializable]
public class GenericListContainer<T> where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    public GenericListContainer()
    {

    }

    public GenericListContainer(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        List = list;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IEnumerable<T> List { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Then I changed my webapi method to :

```
[Route("api/system-users/save-collection-async")]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 200)]       
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveSystemUserCollectionAsync([FromBody] GenericListContainer<SystemUser> dto)
{
    var response = await _systemUserService.SaveSystemUserCollectionAsync(dto.List);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

This method returns the saved user's id (Guid in my case).

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I like this solution, it is very scalable!

Answer (score 0):

Why you use interface type in method? Looks like web API, has no idea what kind of instance should be used for materialize messages argument. Seems that you have to write custom model binder for this action.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using an interface type because I need to be able to post a list of different types of messages in one API call. I already said that I think the problem is the interface type not being converted to a concrete type. An example of what you are describing would be helpful.

Comment: Firstly you have to send some data for specifying concrete type of IMessageApiEntity in your request. then you should implement your IModelBinder ([small example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)) and after all replace [FromBody] attribute to the [ModelBinder(typeof(YourCustomModelBinderTypeName))] for your "messages" method parameter